# Is there a command to change terminal transparency?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I want to define a Bash function that changes the terminal transparency so i can use it like a command. Currently I do something like this for changing the terminal title:

In the .bashrc file i have:

```
title() 
{
echo -en "\033]2;$1\007"
}
```

And when i want to change it i just type:

```
title "Awesome Terminal"
```

I just can't figure out how to do the same with the transparency.

Comment: what kind of desktop do you use?

Comment: Escape sequences such as the one that changes the title are wholly subject to terminal support. The title bar sequence is fairly old and well supported by most terminals. You would need to consult the documentation for your terminal emulator to see if it recognizes any such sequence for transparency.

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/74114/how-to-make-terminal-semi-transparent

Comment: That was one of the first things i saw when searching and not what i want to achieve. I want a function that changes the transparency without needing to restart the OS or the terminal, kind of like going to Edit>Profile preferences>Background> Click on the Transparent background radio button and setting a transparency value, but all this in a function so that i can run it as a command with immediate effect(not needing a restart)

Comment: What terminal emulator do you use? What gives `echo $TERM`?

Comment: I use GNOME Terminal 3.6.1. echo $TERM gives xterm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the below command

```
gconftool-2 -s -t string /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_type transparent
```

Comment: This does the job. Now i just need to figure out how to control the transparency level and how to detect the background type in order to switch between them with the same command.